# Adding a segment controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My code so far;

```
    UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 45)];
    [segment insertSegmentWithTitle:@"OPEN THE DOOR" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

I have 3 segments in the segment controller, `open the door`,`no` & `.` . I need to adjust the width of each segment based on the its title.

for example `open the door` requires more width and `no` requires a little. the `.` requires very little that the other 2 segments.

I tried `[segment setWidth:200 forSegmentAtIndex:0];` to increase the width but it didn't work. How can i do this ?

Comment: Are you setting some action also on segment?

Comment: Yes `[segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Comment: I don't see how that's germane to his question about the widths, even though I agree he does need to set an action.

Comment: try setting the width as the last statement, there is similar problem sometime back and that works for me. There are some resetting issue here. Just try with this and let me know if that works for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using iOS 5 try using the `apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent` property so simply set

```
segment.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;
```

(and get rid of your existing code to set widths)

Comment: Yes, i'm using iOS 5 let me try it out

Comment: After you try it out, I am just curious, why is "." the title of a segment? :)